# Access urlpatterns variable from urls.py in views.py

Tags: django, url

I am trying to access urlpatterns variable from url.py in view.py. but it gives error

Checkout my following code.

```
from testproject.urls import *

print urlpatterns
```

it gives following error.

```
NameError: name 'urlpattern' is not defined
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Well firstly, your error does not match your code. Secondly, why are you trying to do this? There shouldn't be a reason for needing the url patterns themselves. What, *exactly*, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to print `urlpattern` instead of `urlpatterns`. Are you sure this is correct?

To print `urlpatterns` you have to:

- From urls.py you should be able to print it directly because `urlpatterns` is defined here.
- From views.py you have to import the right urls.py file based on where it is. If you want to import the main urls.py then `from project_name.urls import urlpatterns`. If you want to import the urls.py of an app then `from project_name.app_name.urls import urlpatterns`.

NOTE: Remember explicit is always better than implicit, so instead of `from testproject.urls import *` is better `from testproject.urls import urlpatterns`